# unable to start service when it is in external library with seperate package

Tags: android, android-studio

Following is development environment

```
compileSdkVersion 22 buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "techsys.service.app.serverhostapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0" }
```

Created one android library which has sticky service, this library is included in one android application. This Service which is inside library is declared in application manifest file as

```
    <service
        android:name="techsys.service.app.appserver.uniqueservice"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"

        >
    </service>
```

This service is started in application like

```
context.bindService(new Intent(context, uniqueservice.class), conn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

This service aidl interface file is included in application with library package folder path.

Compilation and build successful but looks like some fundamental problem.

Note : If service is included without library then it works good.

This gives following error :-

```
    05-18 17:27:52.900 27195-27195/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp D/MainActivity: onCreate
05-18 17:27:52.900 27195-27195/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp D/MainActivity: uniqueuservice bindService()
05-18 17:27:52.900 27195-27195/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp D/MainActivity: bind uniqueuservice Service
05-18 17:27:52.954 27195-27195/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp D/MainActivity: onStart
05-18 17:27:52.955 27195-27195/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp D/AppTracker: App Event: start
05-18 17:27:52.987 27195-27195/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp D/AbstractTracker: Event success
05-18 17:27:52.988 27195-27195/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp D/ThreadedRenderer: mThreadGroupCpuId 3 mRenderThreadCpuId 0 affinity
05-18 17:27:52.994 27195-27195/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@3d0c23f6 time:8758912
05-18 17:27:53.020 27762-27762/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art: Incompatible structural change detected: Structural change of techsys.service.app.appserver.Iuniqueservice$Stub is hazardous (/data/data/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp/cache/slice-exploded-aar-appserver-debug_e627187da9024749a2416db2406342c5fa9d214e-classes.dex at compile time, /data/data/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp/cache/slice-slice_9-classes.dex at runtime): Direct method count off: 2 vs 4
05-18 17:27:53.020 27762-27762/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art: Ltechsys/service/app/appserver/Iuniqueservice$Stub; (Compile time):
05-18 17:27:53.020 27762-27762/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:  Static fields:
05-18 17:27:53.020 27762-27762/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:   Ljava/lang/String; DESCRIPTOR
05-18 17:27:53.020 27762-27762/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:   I TRANSACTION_multiple
05-18 17:27:53.020 27762-27762/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:  Instance fields:
05-18 17:27:53.020 27762-27762/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:  Direct methods:
05-18 17:27:53.020 27762-27762/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:   <init>()V
05-18 17:27:53.020 27762-27762/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:   asInterface(Landroid/os/IBinder;)Ltechsys/service/app/appserver/Iuniqueservice;
05-18 17:27:53.020 27762-27762/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:  Virtual methods:
05-18 17:27:53.020 27762-27762/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:   asBinder()Landroid/os/IBinder;
05-18 17:27:53.020 27762-27762/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:   onTransact(ILandroid/os/Parcel;Landroid/os/Parcel;I)Z
05-18 17:27:53.020 27762-27762/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art: Ltechsys/service/app/appserver/Iuniqueservice$Stub; (Runtime):
05-18 17:27:53.020 27762-27762/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:  Static fields:
05-18 17:27:53.020 27762-27762/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:   Lcom/android/tools/fd/runtime/IncrementalChange; $change
05-18 17:27:53.020 27762-27762/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:   Ljava/lang/String; DESCRIPTOR
05-18 17:27:53.020 27762-27762/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:   I TRANSACTION_multiple
05-18 17:27:53.020 27762-27762/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:  Instance fields:
05-18 17:27:53.020 27762-27762/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:  Direct methods:
05-18 17:27:53.020 27762-27762/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:   <init>()V
05-18 17:27:53.020 27762-27762/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:   <init>([Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/android/tools/fd/runtime/InstantReloadException;)V
05-18 17:27:53.020 27762-27762/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:   access$super(Ltechsys/service/app/appserver/Iuniqueservice$Stub;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
05-18 17:27:53.020 27762-27762/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:   asInterface(Landroid/os/IBinder;)Ltechsys/service/app/appserver/Iuniqueservice;
05-18 17:27:53.020 27762-27762/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:  Virtual methods:
05-18 17:27:53.020 27762-27762/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:   asBinder()Landroid/os/IBinder;
05-18 17:27:53.020 27762-27762/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:   onTransact(ILandroid/os/Parcel;Landroid/os/Parcel;I)Z
05-18 17:27:53.020 27762-27762/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


                                                                                              --------- beginning of crash
05-18 17:27:53.021 27762-27762/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                              Process: techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote, PID: 27762
                                                                                              java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Structural change of techsys.service.app.appserver.Iuniqueservice$Stub is hazardous (/data/data/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp/cache/slice-exploded-aar-appserver-debug_e627187da9024749a2416db2406342c5fa9d214e-classes.dex at compile time, /data/data/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp/cache/slice-slice_9-classes.dex at runtime): Direct method count off: 2 vs 4
                                                                                              Ltechsys/service/app/appserver/Iuniqueservice$Stub; (Compile time):
                                                                                               Static fields:
                                                                                                Ljava/lang/String; DESCRIPTOR
                                                                                                I TRANSACTION_multiple
                                                                                               Instance fields:
                                                                                               Direct methods:
                                                                                                <init>()V
                                                                                                asInterface(Landroid/os/IBinder;)Ltechsys/service/app/appserver/Iuniqueservice;
                                                                                               Virtual methods:
                                                                                                asBinder()Landroid/os/IBinder;
                                                                                                onTransact(ILandroid/os/Parcel;Landroid/os/Parcel;I)Z
                                                                                              Ltechsys/service/app/appserver/Iuniqueservice$Stub; (Runtime):
                                                                                               Static fields:
                                                                                                Lcom/android/tools/fd/runtime/IncrementalChange; $change
                                                                                                Ljava/lang/String; DESCRIPTOR
                                                                                                I TRANSACTION_multiple
                                                                                               Instance fields:
                                                                                               Direct methods:
                                                                                                <init>()V
                                                                                                <init>([Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/android/tools/fd/runtime/InstantReloadException;)V
                                                                                                access$super(Ltechsys/service/app/appserver/Iuniqueservice$Stub;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
                                                                                                asInterface(Landroid/os/IBinder;)Ltechsys/service/app/appserver/Iuniqueservice;
                                                                                               Virtual methods:
                                                                                                asBinder()Landroid/os/IBinder;
                                                                                                onTransact(ILandroid/os/Parcel;Landroid/os/Parcel;I)Z
                                                                                               (declaration of 'techsys.service.app.appserver.uniqueservice$1' appears in /data/data/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-exploded-aar-appserver-debug_e627187da9024749a2416db2406342c5fa9d214e-classes.dex)
                                                                                                  at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
                                                                                                  at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
                                                                                                  at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
                                                                                                  at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:321)
                                                                                                  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
                                                                                                  at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader$DelegateClassLoader.findClass(IncrementalClassLoader.java:90)
                                                                                                  at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader.findClass(IncrementalClassLoader.java:62)
                                                                                                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                                                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                                                                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                                                                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                                                                  at techsys.service.app.appserver.uniqueservice.<init>(uniqueservice.java:13)
                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                                                  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1606)
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2780)
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:155)
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1406)
                                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:139)
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5298)
                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
05-18 17:27:53.024 27762-27762/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote D/AppTracker: App Event: crash
05-18 17:27:54.164 27803-27803/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art: Incompatible structural change detected: Structural change of techsys.service.app.appserver.Iuniqueservice$Stub is hazardous (/data/data/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp/cache/slice-exploded-aar-appserver-debug_e627187da9024749a2416db2406342c5fa9d214e-classes.dex at compile time, /data/data/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp/cache/slice-slice_9-classes.dex at runtime): Direct method count off: 2 vs 4
05-18 17:27:54.164 27803-27803/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art: Ltechsys/service/app/appserver/Iuniqueservice$Stub; (Compile time):
05-18 17:27:54.164 27803-27803/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:  Static fields:
05-18 17:27:54.164 27803-27803/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:   Ljava/lang/String; DESCRIPTOR
05-18 17:27:54.164 27803-27803/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:   I TRANSACTION_multiple
05-18 17:27:54.164 27803-27803/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:  Instance fields:
05-18 17:27:54.164 27803-27803/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:  Direct methods:
05-18 17:27:54.164 27803-27803/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:   <init>()V
05-18 17:27:54.164 27803-27803/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:   asInterface(Landroid/os/IBinder;)Ltechsys/service/app/appserver/Iuniqueservice;
05-18 17:27:54.164 27803-27803/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:  Virtual methods:
05-18 17:27:54.164 27803-27803/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:   asBinder()Landroid/os/IBinder;
05-18 17:27:54.164 27803-27803/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:   onTransact(ILandroid/os/Parcel;Landroid/os/Parcel;I)Z
05-18 17:27:54.164 27803-27803/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art: Ltechsys/service/app/appserver/Iuniqueservice$Stub; (Runtime):
05-18 17:27:54.164 27803-27803/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:  Static fields:
05-18 17:27:54.164 27803-27803/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:   Lcom/android/tools/fd/runtime/IncrementalChange; $change
05-18 17:27:54.164 27803-27803/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:   Ljava/lang/String; DESCRIPTOR
05-18 17:27:54.164 27803-27803/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:   I TRANSACTION_multiple
05-18 17:27:54.164 27803-27803/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:  Instance fields:
05-18 17:27:54.164 27803-27803/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:  Direct methods:
05-18 17:27:54.164 27803-27803/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:   <init>()V
05-18 17:27:54.164 27803-27803/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:   <init>([Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/android/tools/fd/runtime/InstantReloadException;)V
05-18 17:27:54.164 27803-27803/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:   access$super(Ltechsys/service/app/appserver/Iuniqueservice$Stub;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
05-18 17:27:54.164 27803-27803/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:   asInterface(Landroid/os/IBinder;)Ltechsys/service/app/appserver/Iuniqueservice;
05-18 17:27:54.164 27803-27803/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:  Virtual methods:
05-18 17:27:54.164 27803-27803/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:   asBinder()Landroid/os/IBinder;
05-18 17:27:54.164 27803-27803/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote W/art:   onTransact(ILandroid/os/Parcel;Landroid/os/Parcel;I)Z
05-18 17:27:54.164 27803-27803/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
05-18 17:27:54.166 27803-27803/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                              Process: techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote, PID: 27803
                                                                                              java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Structural change of techsys.service.app.appserver.Iuniqueservice$Stub is hazardous (/data/data/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp/cache/slice-exploded-aar-appserver-debug_e627187da9024749a2416db2406342c5fa9d214e-classes.dex at compile time, /data/data/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp/cache/slice-slice_9-classes.dex at runtime): Direct method count off: 2 vs 4
                                                                                              Ltechsys/service/app/appserver/Iuniqueservice$Stub; (Compile time):
                                                                                               Static fields:
                                                                                                Ljava/lang/String; DESCRIPTOR
                                                                                                I TRANSACTION_multiple
                                                                                               Instance fields:
                                                                                               Direct methods:
                                                                                                <init>()V
                                                                                                asInterface(Landroid/os/IBinder;)Ltechsys/service/app/appserver/Iuniqueservice;
                                                                                               Virtual methods:
                                                                                                asBinder()Landroid/os/IBinder;
                                                                                                onTransact(ILandroid/os/Parcel;Landroid/os/Parcel;I)Z
                                                                                              Ltechsys/service/app/appserver/Iuniqueservice$Stub; (Runtime):
                                                                                               Static fields:
                                                                                                Lcom/android/tools/fd/runtime/IncrementalChange; $change
                                                                                                Ljava/lang/String; DESCRIPTOR
                                                                                                I TRANSACTION_multiple
                                                                                               Instance fields:
                                                                                               Direct methods:
                                                                                                <init>()V
                                                                                                <init>([Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/android/tools/fd/runtime/InstantReloadException;)V
                                                                                                access$super(Ltechsys/service/app/appserver/Iuniqueservice$Stub;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
                                                                                                asInterface(Landroid/os/IBinder;)Ltechsys/service/app/appserver/Iuniqueservice;
                                                                                               Virtual methods:
                                                                                                asBinder()Landroid/os/IBinder;
                                                                                                onTransact(ILandroid/os/Parcel;Landroid/os/Parcel;I)Z
                                                                                               (declaration of 'techsys.service.app.appserver.uniqueservice$1' appears in /data/data/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp/files/instant-run/dex/slice-exploded-aar-appserver-debug_e627187da9024749a2416db2406342c5fa9d214e-classes.dex)
                                                                                                  at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
                                                                                                  at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
                                                                                                  at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
                                                                                                  at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:321)
                                                                                                  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
                                                                                                  at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader$DelegateClassLoader.findClass(IncrementalClassLoader.java:90)
                                                                                                  at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader.findClass(IncrementalClassLoader.java:62)
                                                                                                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                                                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                                                                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                                                                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                                                                  at techsys.service.app.appserver.uniqueservice.<init>(uniqueservice.java:13)
                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                                                  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1606)
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2780)
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:155)
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1406)
                                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:139)
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5298)
                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
05-18 17:27:54.169 27803-27803/techsys.service.app.serverhostapp:remote D/AppTracker: App Event: crash
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service in library and it is binded or started by application like

```
context.bindService(new Intent(context, uniqueservice.class), conn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Then it should be directly linked no need add aidl interface that was causing problem.

Once aidl interface is removed then it started cleanly, and If any other third party application want to bind then they can include aidl interface and bind service.

only need to update process as :remote in host or main application manifest file like

```
    <service
        android:name="techsys.service.app.appserver.uniqueservice"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:process=":remote"
        >
    </service>
```